# How to run MapServer on an existing XAMPP installation?

Tags: mapserver

How can I use MapServer on existing Apache installation? I don't want to install Apache server bundled with MapServer.

Answer (score 4):

I solved my problem. It is just a matter of copying all the contents of cgi-bin folder inside MapServer archive to existing Apache  cgi-bin folder. Hope this may help other people.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I found for compiling on linux:
http://mapserver.org/mapcache/install.html#apache-module-specific-instructions